# libevent: how to override header includes

Tags: c++, header, overriding, libevent

I have this include in my code

```
#include<event.h>
```

which is supposed to include the libevent's header file event.h. But when I see the list of included files it includes this header file

```
Note: including file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\event.h
```

How do I tell the msvc compiler to load libevents event.h header file ? . Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using libevent version 2, it is probably best to [update the includes](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref0_meta.html#_if_you_have_to_work_with_an_old_version_of_libevent) (look at the table). The new include files don't suffer from this specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `#include "event.h"`. It is for user headers and tells the compiler to first look for the header in user-defined paths.

When you use `<>` the compiler will first search in system folders.